Choosing a database for a small desktop application that does not allow the user to edit the database without licensing issues for distributing it
I am currently developing a small application with a local database that will have several users but without concurrency that I will sell through keys.
I need a database that allows the user to not be able to edit the database from any database administrator (Only can use the database in my application). In addition, it does not have licensing problems in being able to be distributed together with my application (I read some limitations) in the same .exe for a good user experience. Any suggestions?

Just don't give them access rights & that should be enough. Lock down the root/admin user and the user which the applciation uses. That should be enough.

I don't think this is doable.
Once you created a desktop application (let's say in Electron) and you use a local database (SQLite, MySQL, etc..) nothing can prevent the user to access what is now actually their own database.
Nothing can prevent a user to do a privilege escalation once they have access to the database that is on their laptop/PC.
What is the problem that you are trying to solve here? I don't understand.

It is my first "serious project" two users will be able to have access to the same computer but no one can edit the database outside of my application. The context is of a small business in which the owner leaves an employee in charge of the store, this employee will not have access to the database, he will only be able to do so from the application (in the application there will be a history of all movements of data)

@Lund you're either explaining this quite poorly or I don't get it at all either. What exactly would be preventing the databases from being edited? Like, you can protect almost all standard databases with password, do you need anything else? What kind of protection are you expecting?

I agree with @Destroy666. I was thinking you needed some high level of security to protect the code of you application. A Password will be enough for your goal
